# Jquery tag sections with empty input fields using .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple sections, each with form input fields (text and textarea).  Once a page is loaded, I want to look through each section, and if all input fields are empty in the section, I would like to add a class to that section.

The purpose of this is so that I can add a listener and slideToggle these sections.

Here is the code I tried:

```
$('.hide-toggler').each(function() {

    var populatedFields = $(this).parent().siblings('.section-wrap')
                            .find('input:text[value!=""], textarea[value!=""]');

    if(populatedFields.length === 0) {
            $(this).addClass('toggle');
    }
});
```

Here is my JS code:
http://jsfiddle.net/QRHgW/5/

I'm not sure why this isn't working for me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What "isn't working"?  Btw, you should use .next('.section-wrap') instead of .siblings().

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and return `.val() != ""` on `:text` type elements:

```
var populatedFields = $(this).parent().siblings('.section-wrap').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(":text").val() != "";
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QRHgW/8/

Comment: Hey thanks a lot - filter worked!  How come find wasn't doing it?  Also, find(":text, textarea").val() it doesn't work.  Do I need to add a separate || conidtion for that?

Comment: Understand what each selector returns, you're specifying two conditions, so it'll return the array of elements, so calling `.val()` on the array will only return the first value.

Comment: I've tried using each, but cannot figure out how to check for both conditions